# как решить only_full_group_by в laravel eloquent?

Tags: laravel

когда существует $rating выполняется выборка и сортировка по groupBy

но на хостинге выбивает ошибку что мол групируешь по 1 колонки (painters.id) а в select выбираешь все колонки

```
$painters = Painter::where('status', '1')
                ->when($rating, function ($query) use ($rating) {
                    return $query
                            ->leftJoin("reviews", "painters.id", "=", "reviews.painter_id")
                            ->select(DB::raw('painters.*'))
                            ->groupBy("painters.id")
                            ->orderByRaw('AVG(reviews.rating)' .$rating);
                }) ->paginate(20);

//сделал так нет ошибок, но в $painters получается только id которые выбраны "select(DB::raw('painters.id'))"
$painters = Painter::where('status', '1')
                ->when($rating, function ($query) use ($rating) {
                    return $query
                            ->leftJoin("reviews", "painters.id", "=", "reviews.painter_id")
                            ->select(DB::raw('painters.id'))
                            ->groupBy("painters.id")
                            ->orderByRaw('AVG(reviews.rating)' .$rating);
                }) ->paginate(20);
```

тут пишут можно так НО если мы сделаем 'strict' => false, это может привести к ошибке безопасности

```
    'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [
        // Behave like MySQL 5.6
        'strict' => false,

        // Behave like MySQL 5.7
        'strict' => true,
    ]
]
```

так как сделать правильно запрос или что?

Comment: *на хостинге выбивает ошибку что мол групируешь по 1 колонки (painters.id) а в select выбираешь все колонки* Правильно. Неполная группировка даёт результат, который не имеет смысла. Стройте синтаксически правильный запрос. А ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY просто заталкивает проблему так, что её не видно - до тех пор, пока некорректность запроса не аукнется.

Comment: ну как построить правильно? мне нужно выбрать все поля в любом случае, но посортировать по среднему числу рейтинга

Comment: *мне нужно выбрать все поля в любом случае* Ну вот представь. Сгруппировал ты по id. Вот группа с каким-то значением этого id, скажем, 1... в ней две записи, у одной в поле val значение 123, у другой 456. Вывести, однако, можно только одно значение. Вопрос - какое вывести, а какое похерить? и главное - а почему? Именно поэтому подобные поля выводить бессмысленно.

Comment: но а что вы предложите, за решение у paintera много колонок, и эти painters должны отсортироваться у кого выше средний рейтинг, а уже каждый в цикле прокрутится и выведуьтся все его поля

Comment: На уровне Laravel ничего не предложу - я ни хрена там не понимаю. Вот на уровне SQL - могу. Покажите хотя бы структуру всех привлечённых к процессу таблиц (painters, reviews) - вывод соотв. `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Сделаем запрос (или хотя бы поймём, как его сделать) - преобразуем в Laravel код.

Comment: та самые простые таблиы к примеру painters{id name, phone, mail], reviews[id painter_id, rating]

Comment: Не надо мне рассказывать про таблицы - показывайте их точные структуры. И не в комментарии, а добавьте в текст вопроса, с читабельным форматированием.

Comment: PS. Если `painters.id` - это поле первичного ключа таблицы, то для исправления ситуации надо в GROUP BY перечислить ВСЕ поля этой таблицы, которые выводятся запросом, а не только `id`.

Comment: @Akina большое спасибо, я просто еще не указал пару полей которых нет в миграции это created_at и updated_at ВСЕ ЗАРАБОТАЛО!

Answer (score 0):

В консоли mysql, в phpmyadmin или через ssh:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

Но это будет рабоать только до перезагрузки сервиса mysql.

Если добавить в конфиг файл будет всегда работать:

```
sql_mode = ''
```